# Convert array of objects, to object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, morphia

I have a mongo db record like this

```
items: [
  0: {
    key: name,
    value: y
   },
  1: {
     key: module,
     value: z
   }
]
```

And per record my expected output is this

```
{
  name : y,
  module : z
}
```

What is the best mongo db aggregation i should apply to achieve this. I have tried few ways but i am unable to produce output.
We can't use unwind otherwise it will break the relationship between name and module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
aggregate(
[{
    $project: {
        items: {
            $map: {
                input: "$items",
                "in": {
                    "k": "$$this.key",
                    "v": "$$this.value"
                }
            }

        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        items: {
            $arrayToObject: "$items"
        }
    }
}])
```

[Test Code](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TjEj0EJ-CNi)

Answer (score 3):

Query

- the items array is almost ready to become `document {}`
- `$map` to rename `key->k` and `value->v` (those are the field names mongo needs)
- `$arrayToObject` to make the items [] => {}
- and then merge items document with the root document
- and project the `items {}`  (we don't need it anymore the fields are part of the root document now)

*you can combine the 2 `$set` in 1 stage, i wrote it in 2 to be simpler

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70175951-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": 
    {"items": 
      {"$map": 
        {"input": "$items", "in": {"k": "$$this.key", "v": "$$this.value"}}}}},
  {"$set": {"items": {"$arrayToObject": ["$items"]}}},
  {"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": {"$mergeObjects": ["$items", "$$ROOT"]}}},
  {"$project": {"items": 0}}])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. this answer really helped me figure another simpler approach.

Comment: its ok, `replaceRoot` was to get the expected output you posted, if you didn't need it you could do until `$set` like you did.